# Spring serves static content as application/json no matter what

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, static-content

I have a simple Spring Boot app with a static content. I would like the browsers to cache not all but just some of the types, like css. So I added following configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
}
```

But now all the CSS files are server as Content-Type: application/json. Without this code they are served as text/css. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Is there anything I should check or add?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had this exact problem, and it was when the file that was requested did not exist (which can be a typo or an accidentally deleted file). When this happens, Spring returns a json response about the error, but because often 'no-sniff' is enabled, you won't see it in a browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention extension of the file name like *.css want to cache

```
@Configuration
public class BaseMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/css/*.css").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(24 * 3600 * 365); 
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/js/*.js").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(0); 

}
}
```

Comment: I made myself not clear. The files are cached with this code, but they are not served as text/css anymore but as application/json. And this causes me problems.

Comment: i think your missing the type attribute in Html can you please check ``type="text/css"`` ex:- <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`       try below one

Comment: The html already contains: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">`, but I don't think this should do the trick. With the configuration, the response headers for `GET css/test.css` contain `Content-type: application/json' and expiration in one year. If I remove this configuration, the reposnse headers contain 'Content-type: text/css' and 'Expire: 0' (and several others for not caching the content). So I assume this configuration somehow messes with mime-types, but I am not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and applying this configuration by:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/*.css")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/img/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(0);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.png")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(0);

}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
    return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
}
```

The resolver is important in this case.

I assume that I made some mistakes when using Spring Boot features and the `@EnableWebMvc` helped a lot.